# Background download stuck at 99%?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been playing SW:TOR for about a week now, and the game has been completing the download in the background.

It stopped at 99.18% downloaded three days ago. Now, I'm level ten and finished on my planet, but I can't get off the planet because the game "is not fully downloaded". How do I get my computer to finish that last percent of download?

Comment: Try running the launcher as an administrator and not pressing play, but waiting to see if it completes?

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer?

Comment: There was a recent issue Bioware had with the patcher and a bug on their part. Does their support post http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=683059 help any?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue with the patch streaming mode. Now that you're done the starter planet you don't need it, so you can disable it and hopefully the regular patch with work.

To do that, go to the folder where SWTOR is installed and open the `launcher.settings` file. Find each of these three lines:

```
, "PatchingMode": "{ \"swtor\": \"BR\" }"
, "bitraider_disable": false
, "P2PEnabled": "true"
```

and replace them with these three:

```
, "PatchingMode": "{ \"swtor\": \"SSN\" }"
, "bitraider_disable": true
, "P2PEnabled": "false"
```

This might cause a redownload of the game, but it should complete this time.

Comment: can you possibly give me more step by step directions... I couldn't figure it out

Comment: @AndrewKallas - I will be honest with you there is only one step.  Could you post the contents of the file in question.  Might help Matthew provide additional details.

Comment: The file is in the game folder: "C:\Program Files\Electronic Arts\BioWare\Star Wars - The Old Republic", for example.
Edit line 10 to make it read , "PatchingMode": "{ \"swtor\": \"SSN\" }".
May be, it is necessary to edit the next line and make it to
, "bitraider_download_complete": {"swtor": false }

Comment: I did what the above told me too , and I ended up restarting the download with English vid.... is this supposed to happen ?

Comment: @Nathanael The launcher is super buggy. At this point you could try copying the *. settings and *. version files from a completely patched original (non Bitraider) install and then doing a Repair, but if you had that install it'd be easiest just to copy the entirety of it.